# How to get Clipboard Image's height and width?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to get Clipboard Image's height and width?

I need a code like following;

```
    If My.Computer.Clipboard.ContainsImage Then
        MsgBox(Clipboard.Image(1).Height) 'This line is not real code.
        MsgBox(Clipboard.Image(1).Width)  'This line is not real code.
    End If
```

I need image size because I want to be sure that if I will paste correct image!

Comment: Well have you looked at the GetImage option in clipboard?

Comment: I need image size because I want to be sure that if I will paste correct image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Clipboard.GetImage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1) like so:

```
 Dim returnImage As System.Drawing.Image = Nothing
 If Clipboard.ContainsImage() Then
    returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage()
    If returnImage.Height != WantedImageHeight || returnImage.Width != WantedImageWidth Then
        MsgBox('The image is not correct')
    End If
 End If
```

Comment: I need image size because I want to be sure that if I will paste correct image!

Comment: I can not convert this C# code to vb.net code. Any support?

Comment: Of course :-) Sorry... Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {
      System.Drawing.Image tempImg =  Clipboard.GetImage();
      int widthOfImg = tempImg.Width;
      int heightOfImg = tempImg.Height; 
    }
```